# How to set up elementary os daily?

Tags: ppa

I have an Ubuntu VM and I want to set it up with elementary OS daily, but the packages inside are throwing dependency errors for packages inside the ppa (!) and I also can't find the package `libhandy-1-0` that is requested by pantheon terminal and switchboard. How can I install it all?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [elementary os-patches PPA](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/os-patches) that likely contains some of the required packages. However, a lot of elementary packages in daily have now dropped support for elementary OS 5.x (bionic/hera) as we're working towards the release of elementary OS 6.0.

So you may find that this still won't work due to dependencies that simply aren't available in elementary OS 5.x.